# SQL Server 2008 - Return not null values from a CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, case

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
    when PERSONNUM in ('x','y','z')
    then 'Home'
    end as HomeEmployees
    when PERSONNUM in ('a','b','c')
    then 'Away'
    end as AwayEmployees
FROM dbo.ALLTOTALS
where PERSONNUM in ('a','b','c','x','y','z')
    and HomeEmployees is not null
```

--multiple whens based upon select PERSONNUM fields

Comment: Logic question. Would like to return non-null values only from my created column. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why not modify your `WHERE` clause from

```
where HomeEmployees is not null
```

into

```
WHERE PERSONNUM IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

so only records with values of `x , y, z` in column `PERSONNUM` are only selected.

Comment: @user2800758 - After which `select 'Home' as HomeEmployees` should do. No need for the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also project the case into an alias and then filter it with an outer query, like so:

```
SELECT * -- Or better still, explicitly identify each needed column
FROM
(
  SELECT *, -- Or better still, explicitly identify each needed column
    CASE 
        WHEN PERSONNUM in ('x','y','z')
        THEN 'Home'
        END AS HomeEmployees
    FROM AllTotals
) AS FilteredEmployees 
WHERE 
  FilteredEmployees.HomeEmployees IS NOT NULL;
```

Or as a CTE:

```
WITH FilteredEmployees AS
(
  SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN PERSONNUM in ('x','y','z')
        THEN 'Home'
        END AS HomeEmployees
    FROM AllTotals
)
SELECT *
  FROM FilteredEmployees
  WHERE FilteredEmployees.HomeEmployees IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Logical order of execution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)(see section "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement") for the following `SELECT` statement:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID      INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Date]  SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    WorkingTime INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID  INT NULL
);
INSERT  @MyTable ([Date], WorkingTime, EmployeeID)
SELECT  '20130801', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130802', 0, 124 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130803', 0, 125; 

SELECT  x.ID,
        CASE WHEN x.ID % 2 = 1 THEN x.ID END AS EmployeeID
FROM    @MyTable x
WHERE   EmployeeID IS NOT NULL;
```

is

1. FROM @myTable x
2. WHERE EmployeeID IS NOT NULL ( <=> WHERE x.EmployeeID IS NOT NULL )
3. SELECT x.ID, CASE ... END AS EmployeeID

As you can see, `CASE ... END AS EmployeeID` expression is evaluated **AFTER** `WHERE` clause. And this means also that `EmployeeID IS NOT NULL` predicate references `x.EmployeeID` column and not the `EmployeeID` alias from `SELECT` clause.

This is the reason I get the following results:

```
ID          EmployeeID
----------- -----------
1           1
2           NULL
3           3
```

If you want to filter by `EmployeeID` alias then you could use one of these solutions:

```
SELECT  x.ID,
        CASE WHEN x.ID % 2 = 1 THEN x.ID END AS EmployeeID
FROM    @MyTable x
WHERE   CASE WHEN x.ID % 2 = 1 THEN x.ID END IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  x.ID,
        CASE WHEN x.ID % 2 = 1 THEN x.ID END AS EmployeeID
FROM    @MyTable x
) src
WHERE   src.EmployeeID IS NOT NULL;
```

**Note:** It's not a good idea to use an alias with the same name as a column name. This create confusion.